# Postgres партицирование и общая логика?

Tags: python, postgresql

есть таблица с начала года на 38 млн записей. индексы стоят, но вот инзерт по 2 секунды - не к добру. решил сделать партицирование. на тестовом серваке выборка без индексов увеличилась в 60 раз. вроде ляпота. но вот заливалось это в тестовую базу 10 часов.

вопрос 1 - если я просто повешу функцию патрицирования на живую базу, не замаричиваясь предыдущими данными - как это скажется на быстродействии?

вопрос 2 - если данные предпожим трехмесячной давности хранить не как значения по минутам, а среднее за час - как это корректно сделать?

### UPD

нет будут у меня старые данные. просто они будут лежать в мастере. а вот новые будут писаться в партиции. а по поводу функции (скорее уж тригер) - как мне её по времени запускать? я уж больше думаю о скрипте на питоне, который раз в месяц будет дампить старые партиции, чистить таблицу и записывать агрегированные данные. но вот в партиции 7 млн строк. потянет ли питон? было б наверно правильно демона\скрипт написать для медленной обработки патриции. например раз в 30 минут брал бы данные из партиции (например за один день), обрабатывал их, удалял старые, заливал новые агрегированные. а вот про флаг обработаны данные или нет хорошо придумано. но можно и от интервала скакать.

---

3 вопрос - я использую данные для рисования статистики. То есть длинные прямые с одинаковым значением можно и через 2 значения построить. Есть ли способ "выкусить" длинные поток одинаковых данных

Comment: на вопрос 3 есть решения, но может Вам стоит создать отдельный вопрос. Что бы не все в одном вопросе было?

Comment: @des1roer, в следующий раз оформляйте, пожалуйста, отдельные вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если Вы использовали MasterTable. И правильно создали алгоритм порцирования, тогда проблем не будет. Просто у Вас не будут старые данные.
2. Для таких работ как обработка данных с промежуточной времени лучше сделать функцию. И запускать функцию каждый час. Функция сама выберет данные, обрабатывает и сохраняет на новую таблицу (или этому же с флагом обработанный), и удаляет не нужные данные (или перемешает в другую таблицу - архив)
3. Самое лучшее если Вы еще не успели сделать, создайте функцию для Insert в таблицу. И тогда появится возможность дополнительно делать вспомогательные действия.

P.S. для задачи 1 проверьте индексацию еще раз. У меня таблица с 90 млн записей работает без проблем. Может индексы нужно подправить?

---

К дополнении вопроса.

4. Есть функции в postgres. Не триггеры. Можно их запускать

   ```
   select <имя функции>;
   ```

можно сделать как вы сказали запуск каждый час. Функция может сама оправлять временем. То есть берет время и само создает отрезок (к примеру 1 час) при каждом запуске или в цикле. и по порциям делать `commit`

Comment: индексы хороши при выборке. но никак не помогают при вставке. выборка данных мс занимает

Comment: а вставку через функцию пробовали?

Comment: нет не пробовал